# How to increment the Assembly version on each build in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-6

How to increment the Assembly version on each build in TeamCity using Build Runner Type Visual Studio Sln File?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeamCity 6.0 allows to create multiple build steps for your build configuration. So, with a first build step you can run some script which [increases Assembly version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610414/automatic-assembly-version-number-management-in-vs2008) (you can obtain it from current build number as build.number system property). The second build step will run real sln runner.

Answer (score 4):

TeamCity 6.5 and above come with an AssemblyInfoPatcher which you can configure with a static value or with TeamCity variables. The simplest approach if you just want to change the version number.

- Edit your build configuration
- Edit *Build Step*
- Add *build feature*
- Select *AssemblyInfo patcher*
- select the variable(s) to use for your version number

note: this simple feature assumes that your assemblyinfo files are in the default location (under Properties).