# MSBuild autoincrement version - TFS2010

Tags: msbuild, build

I created a build definition with some MSBuild Arguments (/target:Publish /property:PublishDir=\mypc\tmp\ /property:ApplicationVersion=1.0.0.1)

What's the best way to increment the ApplicationVersion for each build automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I suggest you make sure all projects in your solution use a shared AssemblyInfo file (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610414/automatic-assembly-version-number-management-in-vs2008/610443#610443)).

Then alter your build script so the file is checked out, the version number increased and saved, then checked in again.

To do that have a look at the [community build tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/), or [create your own](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-msbuild-tasks-in-csharp).